# System call with inline comment from Ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, system, exec

I want to run a command with inline comment like

```
sleep 1 # first sync call
sleep 1 # second sync call
# etc
```

But I can't pass it to `exec` in Ruby

```
fork{  exec "sleep 1 # first async call" }
fork{  exec "sleep 1 # second async call" }
```

It traces warnings.

So how could I pass some comments into system call with `exec`.

*I need it for logging*

PS: As a variant: `fork{ exec "sh -c 'sleep 1' # first async" }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `command ...` or `exec "command ..."`, everything after the first word is used as arguments to the command, so your comment is not being interpreted as a comment.

Regardless, your logging wouldn't be able to capture this, since it's only a comment — instead, you might just want to `puts` something before calling `exec`.

Comment: Ok, now I understand this dark side of the Moon. Thank you